# TypeError: connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a table that shows rows called from DB, every row have a button that opens another window, I need to pass some variable to the other windows using the function, here is how am doing it :

that is where i created the table and selected from DB :

```
number = 0
queue = 1
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM clinic WHERE Extra_Notice = 'x-ray is required'")
test_list = cur.fetchall()
for row in test_list:
    c_id = row[0]
    p_id = row[1]
    print p_id
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE id = '%s'"%(p_id))
    pt = cur.fetchall()
    for pt_row in pt:
        pt_name = pt_row[1]
        pt_age = pt_row[2]
        pt_address = pt_row[4]
        pt_phone = pt_row[3]
    self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Make Operation')
    self.button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #4f81bc; color: white;")
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.open_item_entry(p_id))
    rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
    self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)
    self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(rowPosition , 0, self.button)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(pt_phone)))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 2, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(pt_address)))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 3, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(pt_age)))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 4, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(pt_name)))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 5, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(c_id)))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 6, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(queue)))
    queue += 1
```

i tried to bind the button to the function in this line `self.button.clicked.connect(self.open_item_entry(p_id))`

and here is the function :

```
def open_item_entry(self, pt_name):
    self.window = QtGui.QDialog()
    self.ui = Ui_Report1()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
    self.window.show()
```

and I get this error when I try to click the button :

`TypeError: connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'NoneType'`

Comment: The problem is that you're calling `self.open_item_entry(p_id)`, and passing the result of that (which is presumably `None`) to `connect`. You want to pass a function that _calls_ that, which you can do with `functools.partial(self.open_item_entry, p_id)` or `lambda: self.open_item_entry(p_id)`.

Comment: `open_item_entry()` has no `return` statement, therefore it returns `None` back to its caller, so you're effectively calling `connect(None)`.

Comment: The best duplicate questions are about tkinter rather than PyQt. I also found one that's about the exact same issue in the `defaultdict` constructor, for variety, but nothing specifically about PyQt. So please take a look and make sure you understand the answers even though the `TypeError` you get looks a bit different; if not, I'm sure we can find something Qt-specific (even if the explanation isn't as good).